# Getting error when trying to use Angular material drag and drop

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

Be low is the error I am getting when I try to drag and drop:

> zone-evergreen.js:172 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   '_startReceiving' of undefined
>
> zone-evergreen.js:651 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read
>   property '_stopReceiving' of undefined ; Zone:  ; Task:
>   Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property '_stopReceiving'
>   of undefined

**ts file:**

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>, source, iTabId) {
    moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check if you has defined in each CdkDropList the propertie **cdkDropListData** - must be an array you has defined in yout .ts.  check too the version of material you use

Comment: @Eliseo here is the array: `[20, 21, 22]`

Comment: @Eliseo We need this array like this: `["20", "21", "22"]` and it worked.

Comment: In my opinion, use an array of string or number should be indifferent, the only thing to take account is that the two arrays must be the same type

Comment: I can confirm that `number` type ids cause this cryptic error.

Comment: @BenRacicot yes, that was the error!